# Why is Black Magic Probe Uart loopback is not working?

Tags: embedded, remote-debugging

When connecting a Black Magic Probe to my mac i'm not able to receive any data when connecting UART RX to UART TX. I tried updating the firmware to the latest version without success.

I tried multiple Black Magic probes, both on Mac and Windows without success. The UART TX led on the board blinks when transmitting. I verified the connection was to the correct device endpoint (second interface of the device). When using an oscilloscoop I did not see and data transmitted on the TX output port.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Black Magic Probe does not power the target. The Black Magic Probe uses levels shifters that require a reference voltage provided by the target to be present. Without this reference level the levels shifter buffer will not output any signals or receive any signals.

It is possible to use the 3.3V LDO on the Black Magic Probe as a reference by using this command in GDB: "monitor tpwr enable". Use the command: "monitor tpwr" to validate the target is powered by the Black Magic Probe. Please be careful the target supports 3.3V power and the total power consumption is limited. By supplying the power to the target the level shifters have a reference level and a UART loopback should work by connecting the RX and TX pin.